# Blur just one object in Unity

Tags: unity, rendering, camera, graphic-effects, vuforia

I've recently encountered a problem where I needed to blur an object that is inside another object. I've tried several methods to fix this but none of them works properly. In the screenshot below, renders have to happen in order so that the shape is preserved but the middle portion is blurred. 
[image]

My current setup is this: 3 Cameras each rendering different objects (one object per camera), the white one below is actually a depth mask and only the camera that renders it is clearing the depth mask. The others aren't clearing anything.
[image]

When I apply a blur mask on the camera that has the middle portion (Object in the blurmask layer), everything else gets blurred too (there's a background off screen which shouldn't get blurred, that's the reason for Vuforia tag). How do I solve this? Frankly, I'm absolutely stumped at this point and willing to try anything (comments are welcome too).

This is what I have right now (The longer cylinder had a depth-shader in its material which clears any 3D object parts behind it):
[image]

Comment: The screenshot is from a test build so the blur mask says it clears depth but it doesn't right now, just ignore that part.

Comment: This sounds like something which is better solved by assigning a different material with a different shader to the mesh which needs to be blurred.

Comment: @Philipp The shader blurs the texture on the object (a sharp edged object with a blurry texture), what I want is to blur the object itself (the edges should look blurry too). Is there any way to make a part of the object invisible and the inside texture into a blurry one? (Essentially putting the pink object as a texture on top of the white one, but that white one is a depth mask, I'll put a new screenshot to show the effect I'm making)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shader that [I've come across in another post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/151582/blur-and-gray-shader) here seems to do the job quite well:

```
Shader "Custom/SimpleGrabPassBlur" {
    Properties {
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _BumpAmt  ("Distortion", Range (0,128)) = 10
        _MainTex ("Tint Color (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _BumpMap ("Normalmap", 2D) = "bump" {}
        _Size ("Size", Range(0, 20)) = 1
    }

    Category {

        // We must be transparent, so other objects are drawn before this one.
        Tags { "Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Opaque" }


        SubShader {

            // Horizontal blur
            GrabPass {                     
                Tags { "LightMode" = "Always" }
            }
            Pass {
                Tags { "LightMode" = "Always" }

                CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag
                #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                struct appdata_t {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float2 texcoord: TEXCOORD0;
                };

                struct v2f {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float4 uvgrab : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                v2f vert (appdata_t v) {
                    v2f o;
                    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                    #if UNITY_UV_STARTS_AT_TOP
                    float scale = -1.0;
                    #else
                    float scale = 1.0;
                    #endif
                    o.uvgrab.xy = (float2(o.vertex.x, o.vertex.y*scale) + o.vertex.w) * 0.5;
                    o.uvgrab.zw = o.vertex.zw;
                    return o;
                }

                sampler2D _GrabTexture;
                float4 _GrabTexture_TexelSize;
                float _Size;

                half4 frag( v2f i ) : COLOR {
//                  half4 col = tex2Dproj( _GrabTexture, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(i.uvgrab));
//                  return col;

                    half4 sum = half4(0,0,0,0);

                    #define GRABPIXEL(weight,kernelx) tex2Dproj( _GrabTexture, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(float4(i.uvgrab.x + _GrabTexture_TexelSize.x * kernelx*_Size, i.uvgrab.y, i.uvgrab.z, i.uvgrab.w))) * weight

                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.05, -4.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.09, -3.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.12, -2.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.15, -1.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.18,  0.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.15, +1.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.12, +2.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.09, +3.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.05, +4.0);

                    return sum;
                }
                ENDCG
            }

            // Vertical blur
            GrabPass {                         
                Tags { "LightMode" = "Always" }
            }
            Pass {
                Tags { "LightMode" = "Always" }

                CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag
                #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                struct appdata_t {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float2 texcoord: TEXCOORD0;
                };

                struct v2f {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float4 uvgrab : TEXCOORD0;
                };

                v2f vert (appdata_t v) {
                    v2f o;
                    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                    #if UNITY_UV_STARTS_AT_TOP
                    float scale = -1.0;
                    #else
                    float scale = 1.0;
                    #endif
                    o.uvgrab.xy = (float2(o.vertex.x, o.vertex.y*scale) + o.vertex.w) * 0.5;
                    o.uvgrab.zw = o.vertex.zw;
                    return o;
                }

                sampler2D _GrabTexture;
                float4 _GrabTexture_TexelSize;
                float _Size;

                half4 frag( v2f i ) : COLOR {
//                  half4 col = tex2Dproj( _GrabTexture, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(i.uvgrab));
//                  return col;

                    half4 sum = half4(0,0,0,0);

                    #define GRABPIXEL(weight,kernely) tex2Dproj( _GrabTexture, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(float4(i.uvgrab.x, i.uvgrab.y + _GrabTexture_TexelSize.y * kernely*_Size, i.uvgrab.z, i.uvgrab.w))) * weight

                    //G(X) = (1/(sqrt(2*PI*deviation*deviation))) * exp(-(x*x / (2*deviation*deviation)))

                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.05, -4.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.09, -3.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.12, -2.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.15, -1.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.18,  0.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.15, +1.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.12, +2.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.09, +3.0);
                    sum += GRABPIXEL(0.05, +4.0);

                    return sum;
                }
                ENDCG
            }

            // Distortion
            GrabPass {                         
                Tags { "LightMode" = "Always" }
            }
            Pass {
                Tags { "LightMode" = "Always" }

                CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag
                #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                struct appdata_t {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float2 texcoord: TEXCOORD0;
                };

                struct v2f {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                    float4 uvgrab : TEXCOORD0;
                    float2 uvbump : TEXCOORD1;
                    float2 uvmain : TEXCOORD2;
                };

                float _BumpAmt;
                float4 _BumpMap_ST;
                float4 _MainTex_ST;

                v2f vert (appdata_t v) {
                    v2f o;
                    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                    #if UNITY_UV_STARTS_AT_TOP
                    float scale = -1.0;
                    #else
                    float scale = 1.0;
                    #endif
                    o.uvgrab.xy = (float2(o.vertex.x, o.vertex.y*scale) + o.vertex.w) * 0.5;
                    o.uvgrab.zw = o.vertex.zw;
                    o.uvbump = TRANSFORM_TEX( v.texcoord, _BumpMap );
                    o.uvmain = TRANSFORM_TEX( v.texcoord, _MainTex );
                    return o;
                }

                fixed4 _Color;
                sampler2D _GrabTexture;
                float4 _GrabTexture_TexelSize;
                sampler2D _BumpMap;
                sampler2D _MainTex;

                half4 frag( v2f i ) : COLOR {
                    // calculate perturbed coordinates
                    half2 bump = UnpackNormal(tex2D( _BumpMap, i.uvbump )).rg; // we could optimize this by just reading the x  y without reconstructing the Z
                    float2 offset = bump * _BumpAmt * _GrabTexture_TexelSize.xy;
                    i.uvgrab.xy = offset * i.uvgrab.z + i.uvgrab.xy;

                    half4 col = tex2Dproj( _GrabTexture, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(i.uvgrab));
                    half4 tint = tex2D( _MainTex, i.uvmain ) * _Color;

                    return col * tint;
                }
                ENDCG
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I just made another cylinder on top of the existing one (copy paste), then I enlarged that one by 5% and put a material with this shader on top of it. Though this does blur some other stuff and not just the object, it's still passable in terms of quality. Here's the result:

[image: if the upload is not borked thanks to an imgur ban in my country]